Animated (anime?) series or movie with human heroes using laser guns that can merge beams and enemies with white masks
I am pretty sure I watched an anime series episode (or an anime movie) with human heroes that were using laser guns against enemies that were alien creatures or robots with white masks. The masks were similar to the mask in the Iria anime, I think.
If I remember correctly, the laser beams fired from the pistols by the protagonists were able to merge into one super beam. It must have been in the 80s or 90s. I cannot identify it.

Do you mean like at https://i.sstatic.net/oloSWlA4.png? (Around 0:17 of the trailer at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxGLuBwkSAk)

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Yes. I think the masks were similar to Zeiram mask, but I am not 100% sure.
